# How can I add a button to a child on expandable listview?

Tags: android, button, expandablelistadapter

Sorry, pretty new to java programming. So here it goes...
I have an expandable list view that is populated from my MySQL database via a JSON array. The database is a list of people and the presents they have requested. All working well.
I now want to add a button to a child, but only if a present has not already been bought.

here's my code (abridged)

**ExpandableListAdapter.java**

```
 public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context _context;
    private List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
    // child data in format of header title, child title
    private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;

    public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader, HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
        this._context = context;
        this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
        this._listDataChild = listChildData;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosititon);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        }

        TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);

        txtListChild.setText(childText);
        return convertView;
    }

    private int getItemId() {
        int position = 0;
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return this._listDataHeader.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
        }

        TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
        lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

        return convertView;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
 public class MainActivity extends ProfileActivity {

    ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
    ExpandableListView expListView;
    List<String> listDataHeader;
    HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;

    private ProgressDialog mprocessingdialog;
    private static String url = "http://www.wishlist.feichter.co.uk/android/present_list.php";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mprocessingdialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

        // get the listview
        expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.lvExp);

        // preparing list data
        new DownloadJason().execute();
    }

    /*
     * Preparing the list data
     */
    private class DownloadJason extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();

            //Showing Progress dialog
            mprocessingdialog.setTitle("Please Wait..");
            mprocessingdialog.setMessage("Loading");
            mprocessingdialog.setCancelable(false);
            mprocessingdialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            mprocessingdialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            JSONParser jp = new JSONParser();
            String jsonstr = jp.makeServiceCall(url);
            Log.d("Response = ", jsonstr);

            if (jsonstr != null) {
                // For Header title Arraylist
                listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();

                // Hashmap for child data key = header title and value = Arraylist (child data)
                listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

                try {
                    JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(jsonstr);
                    JSONArray jarray = jobj.getJSONArray("presents_db");

                    for (int hk = 0; hk < jarray.length(); hk++) {
                        JSONObject d = jarray.getJSONObject(hk);

                        // Adding Header data
                        //listDataHeader.add(d.getString("name"));
                        listDataHeader.add(d.getString("name") + "'s presents are: ");

                        // Adding child data for lease offer
                        List<String> members = new ArrayList<String>();

                        //members.add(d.getString("name") + "'s presents are: ");

                        JSONArray xarray = d.getJSONArray("presents_list");
                        for (int i = 0; i < xarray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject a = xarray.getJSONObject(i);
                            if("".equals(a.getString("bought_by"))) {
                                members.add(a.getString("present"));
                                //members.add(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                                //ExpandableListAdapter hello = new test(this);
                                //hello.execute();
                                //View b = findViewById(R.id.BtnToClick);
                                //Button b = findViewById(R.id.BtnToClick);
                                //b.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            }else{
                                members.add(a.getString("present") + "\r\n bought by: " + a.getString("bought_by"));
                            }
                        }

                        // Header into Child data
                        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(hk), members);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please Check internet Connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            mprocessingdialog.dismiss();

            //call constructor
            listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), listDataHeader, listDataChild);

            // setting list adapter
            expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, the `if("".equals(a.getString("bought_by"))) {` function changes what gets displayed in the child, but, how do I add a button?

I know it must be a completely different approach...

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Any button exist on your `list_item` layout?

Comment: Yes, with visibility 'gone'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add button in your child_layout, make the visibility of button to "gone". In getChildView(), check if the present is bought and make the button visible, In else case make the button visibility "gone".

Comment: Thank you Muhammed, but how can I check the json result in 'getChildView()'? That's the bit I am struggling with.

Comment: You can check that with the HashMap in the ExpandableListAdapter. listDataChild will contain the expanded child data, Check your condition inside your getChildView. childText  contains the value of bought_by, So check if("".equals(childText)) {

Comment: Thank you so much again. You are really helping this novice! I didn't know that the HashMap was available across activities. I have now added 'if("".equals(childText)) {
            Button b = convertView.findViewById(R.id.BtnToClick);
            b.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }' in getChildView, but I am still not quite clear....

Comment: Got a bit further...
by adding ' Toast.makeText(_context, childText, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();' to 'getChildView' I am now getting the results of each row. But, how can I check if the row includes 'bought_by'?

Comment: Muhammed, you got me sooo close to the answer. Can you help anymore?

Comment: when do you want to add the button ? When the row contains "bought_by" or if the text is not present ?

Comment: You could add a code to check if the present bought is displayed. Check if(childText.contains("bought by") { button.setVisibility(View.GONE);} else { button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);}

Comment: Thank you sooo much! That did it!